# What is the Terminator T-800 model made of?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

What kind of metal is the Terminator T-800 model made of? Is it titanium or some other metal?

Comment: http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperalloy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The T-800's chassis is typically said to be made of an unspecified "hyperalloy". For example:

> The Terminator's an infiltration unit.  Part man, part machine. Underneath, it's a **hyperalloy** combat chassis, microprocessor-controlled, fully armored.
>
> <sub>**Kyle Reese, [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator.html) from *The Terminator***</sub>

*Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* suggests that T-800s are made out of [**coltan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coltan):

> John Connor: That's coltan; if that's what you're made of, no wonder you're so dense.
>
> Cameron Phillips: Not density, heat resistance. T-600 models had a titanium alloy endoskeleton, but it was vulnerable to heat. Coltan alloys have a much higher melting point.
>
> <sub>***Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, Episode 104: Heavy Metal, quoted from the [Terminator Wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Coltan)**</sub>

Coltan consists of the elements [niobium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niobium) and [tantalum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum) (both metals).

Note, however, that [Cameron is a T-900 series](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron) so it's possible the T-800s are *not* made out of coltan and instead use the titanium alloy that the T-600s used.

Comment: I suspect if the titanium alloy had been used by other models she would have included them. She's not the type to be unspecific.

Comment: Wait a minute. Cameron implies that the T-800s were not vulnerable to heat like the T-600s, but "Uncle Bob" was destroyed by lowering him into molten *steel*, which high a lower melting point than even titanium!

Comment: @JohnSensebe I doubt the writers thought that scene all the way through, but it's likely that a T-800's "brain" chip, which is what really had to be destroyed lest Skynet re-create itself, could not survive immersion in molten steel even if its skeleton could.

Comment: @JohnSensebe It's the *boiling point* of steel that would matter in such a case, since molten steel is somewhere between the melting and boiling points. For instance, titanium *can* melt in molten steel, because the melting point of titanium is below the boiling point of steel.

Comment: According to your link, coltan is an ore, not an alloy.

Comment: @alastair - but it would be a waste of energy to keep the molten steel at a temperature much beyond its melting point, and therefore a waste of money.

Comment: @JohnSensebe It's likely quite complicated and you'd need to talk to a metallurgist; clearly you want as low a temperature as you can get away with, subject to things like viscosity, whether (and which) impurities will burn off or dissolve and so on. FWIW, from Googling a bit, pouring temperature for steel is around the 1600 – 1700°C mark, which is *just* hot enough to melt titanium.

Answer (score 6):

The exact composition is not specified. The T-800 is made of Hyperalloy, which is a durable metallic alloy of **unknown composition** that provides the combat chassis and endoskeleton of several Terminator series(including the T-800).

Both Hyperalloy and Polyalloy are very interesting concepts (that could be scientifically-valid even with today's complex technology), but there is no mention of the exact molecular composition of either of them.

Comment: I believe [unobtanium](https://www.google.com/search?q=unobtanium&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is a crucial part of the recipe.

Comment: @DigitalChris - That was for early models, then they switched to adamantium.

Comment: You should provide source for your link.  This looks like it was copied from the terminator wiki.